# Fast algorithm to remove edge to get DAG

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Given a directed cyclic graph, I want to find if removing a single edge can make the graph a DAG. I came up with a trivial way to do this - remove each edge and check if the graph is cyclic (which takes $\mathcal{O}(\mid E \mid(\mid V \mid + \mid E \mid))$ time, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do this.

Comment: You can use bfs or dfs ( $O(|V| + |E|)$)

Comment: i can find a cycle using bfs/dfs, but how would i find the edge that can be removed to form a DAG? i wrote $\mathcal{O}(\mid E \mid(\mid V \mid + \mid E \mid))$ in the question because i run bfs/dfs for each possible edge removal.

Comment: When running bfs/dfs keep track of the edges that create cycles. You make a decision depending on the set of those edges.

Comment: the set of all edges that create cycles can be at most $\mathcal{O}(\mid E \mid)$ (if every edge is part of some cycle), so it doesn't seem to do faster. note that the original graph can have any number of cycles.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the rooted spanning tree formed by a DFS traversal. You need to study the [back edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Output_of_a_depth-first_search). Here's a picture from Wikipedia showing the different type of edges generated by the traversal:

[image: DFS traversal edge classification]

If you only have one back edge, you can remove it and get a DAG. If you have multiple back edges, you need to find a common, shared tree edge to remove, and it should be one that can't be circumvented using a forward or cross edge.

1. Generate the DFS traversal tree ($\mathcal{O}(|E| + |V|)$).
2. We can find the LCA of all the lower (starting) vertices of our back edges ($\mathcal{O}(|E|\log|V|)$). Call this vertex $b$ (bottom).
3. We can find the lowest ending (top) vertex of a back edge in the DFS tree. Call this vertex $t$ (top). To do this step, it would be handy to remember vertex level when doing the traversal. $\mathcal{O}(|E|)$
4. If $t$ is lower in the tree than $b$, then we have two back edges that don't "share" a common tree edge that can be removed remove, so we would need to remove both of them to get a DAG. Otherwise, we need to interrupt the path along the tree from $t$ to $b$. We can try to do that by removing an edge on it.
5. We need to check if all the tree edges from $t$ to $b$ can be circumvented. That can happen via forward edges, or via a branch and then a cross edge. Thus, we can remove them all, and check if there's still a path from $t$ to $b$. If not, then there is a tree edge between them that is essential to all cycles ($\mathcal{O}(|E| + |V|)$).